# I have html string which i want to convert to DocX Net.Core with FONT AERIAL for example

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openxml

I have converted html to Docx but it has some default font which i dont want.

I am trying htmltoopenxml.dll right now . it converts to docx.

```
     var htmmml = @"<h1>ვახოს დოკუმენტის ქვე კატეგორიახელშეკრულება შრომითი ურთიერთობის შესახებ</h1>" +
            "<p> ერთი მხრივ,&nbsp; [CompanyName]&nbsp;<strong>&nbsp;</strong>(ს.კ.&nbsp; [CompanyCode]) (შემდგომში &bdquo;დამსაქმებელი&ldquo;) და მეორე მხრივ, [Employee]<strong>&nbsp;</strong>(პ.ნ[EmployeeId]) (შემდგომში &bdquo;დასაქმებული&ldquo;) ვდებთ წინამდებარე ხელშეკრულებას შემდეგზე:</p>" +
            "<h2>ხელშეკრულების საგანი</h2><ol><li>დამსაქმებელი დასაქმებულს სამუშაოზე იყვანს [EmployeePosition]-ს პოზიციაზე და დასაქმებული თანხმობას აცხადებს შეასრულოს მასზე დაკისრებული სამუშაო წინამდებარე ხელშეკრულებით დადგენილი პირობების შესაბამისად.</li>" +
            "<li>დამსაქმებელი უხდის დასაქმებულს შესრულებული სამუშაოს საფასურს - ხელფასს[Salary]&nbsp;[Currency] ს<strong>&nbsp;</strong>ოდენობით.&nbsp;</li>" +
            "<li>ხელშეკრულებით გათვალისწინებულ<span style=\"color: rgb(184, 49, 47);\"> პოზიციაზე </span> დასაქმებულის მიღება ხდება ამ ხელშეკრულების საფუძველზე და რაიმე სახის დამატებით აქტს არ საჭიროებს.</li>" +
            "<li>სამუშაოს შესრულების ადგილი, სამუშაო საათები და დასვენების დრო</li>" +
            "<li>დასაქმებულის სამუშაო ადგილია[TownName] კერძოდ [CompanyName]-ის ოფისი.</li>" +
            "<li>დამსაქმებელი გააცნობს დასაქმებულს &nbsp; მის კონკრეტულ ვალდებულებებს დასაქმებულის მიერ თავისი ფუნქციების შესრულების დაწყებისა და მიმდინარეობის პროცესში.</li></ol>" +
            "<p><strong>დასაქმებული ჩვეულებრივ მუშაობს კვირაში ხუთი დღე ორშაბათიდან პარასკევამდე. სამუშაო საათების ხანგრძლივობა კვირაში შეადგენს[TimeAmount] საათის ოდენობით.დამსაქმებელი საკუთარი შეხედულებისამებრ განსაზღვრავს დღის განმავლობაში შრომის საათებს, რის შესახებაც ატყობინებს დასაქმებულს.</strong></p>" +
            "<p>ყოველდღიური დასვენების ხანგრძლივობა შეადგენს [Minutes]&nbsp; წუთს.ყოველდღიური შესვენების დრო არ ითვლება&nbsp; სამუშაო დროის ხანგრძლივობაში.</p>" +
            "<p>დამსაქმებელი სარგებლობს შვებულების უფლებით შრომის კოდექსით გათვალისწინებული პირობების დაცვით.</p>"



byte[] document;
        using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
                var run = new Run();
                if (mainPart == null)
                {
                    mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
                }

                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }

            document = generatedDocument.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Whats you question?

Comment: i want to change font and i cant change that font

Comment: How did you try to change the font?

Comment: well this Open Xml has some ways but it only changes each paragraphs styles and i want to change whole bodies style.  i tried to search for it but couldnt find the way .